# NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть класс WorldGenerator со вложеным циклом. Ошибка возникает на 22 строке

`GameObject block = Instantiate(DB.blocks[0].gObj, new Vector3(x, y, 1), Quaternion.identity);`

Полный текст ошибки:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   WorldGanerator.Generate (System.Int32 size) (at Assets/Scripts/WorldGanerator.cs:22)"

```
public class WorldGanerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PlayerInventoryPanel;
    public GameObject Player;
    DataBase DB;

    private void Start()
    {
        DB = gameObject.AddComponent<DataBase>();
    }

    public void Generate(int size)
    {
        for(int y = -size/2; y < size; y++)
        {
            for (int x = -size/2; x < size; x++)
            {
                GameObject block = Instantiate(DB.blocks[0].gObj, new Vector3(x, y, 1), Quaternion.identity);
                block.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = DB.blocks[0].Img;
            }
        }

        Instantiate(Player, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Функция Generate вызывается из класса Game в Start

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    DataBase DB;
    WorldGanerator WG;

    public GameObject PlayerInventoryPanel;

    private void Start()
    {
        DB = gameObject.AddComponent<DataBase>();
        WG = gameObject.AddComponent<WorldGanerator>();

        DB.Setup();
        WG.Generate(10);

        PlayerInventoryPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте вместо `DB = gameObject.AddComponent<DataBase>();` `DB = gameObject.GetComponent<DataBase>();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В ошибке прописано, что DB имеет значение null.  Почему у вас AddComponent()? AddComponent добавляет компонент GameObject, используйте GetComponent() чтобы получить компонент. В методе Start вы не присваиваете какое либо значение переменной, DB а наоборот. Поэтому DB это null и соответственно появляется ошибка. Поэтому заменитель AddComponent на GetComponent.

Comment: Это не помогло, к тому же в классе Game переменные DB и WG определяются таким же образом, в ошибке вроде написано что проблема в переменной size, но я не могу понять в чём именно